# On the statement of Noether-Lefschetz theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Noether-Lefschetz theorem says that, If $d \geq 4$, then a surface $S \subset \mathbb P^3$ of degree $d$ having general moduli has Picard group $\text{Pic}(S) \cong \mathbb Z.\mathcal O(1)$.

That means if the surface $S$ is of particular kind(of general moduli) then it's Picard group is generated by $\mathcal O_S(1)$ and hence is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. Alternatively one can say the restriction map $\text{Pic}(\mathbb P^3) \to \text{Pic}(S)$ is an isomorphism.

At this point my confusion is regarding the first part of the theorem:" *$S$ having general moduli*".

In the literature it's mentioned that "of general moduli" means that there is a countable union $V$ of subvatrieties of the projective space $\mathbb P^N=|\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(d)|$ of smooth surfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^3$ such that the property $\text{Pic}(X) \cong \mathbb Z$ holds for $X \in \mathbb P^N - V$.

More precisley, does this mean that the first part of the theorem says assume existence of such $V$ with the said property and choose $S \in \mathbb P^N - V$. But then the way we have chosen $S$ we automatically have $\text{Pic}(S) \cong \mathbb Z$(Surely I am missing the point here). Then is the phrase "general moduli"  independent of the surface $S$?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: The theorem means: There exists $V \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ which is a countable union of subvarieties, such that for all $S \in \mathbb{P}^N - V$, it holds that $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^3) \to \operatorname{Pic}(S)$ is an isomorphism. In other words, it *asserts* (not assumes) existence of such a $V$. The surface $S$ is chosen after $V$ is established.

Comment: @ZachTeitler, Thanks a lot for the clarification. Is the existence of such a $V$ for $d \leq 3$ known?

Comment: There is no such V for $d=2$ or 3. Smooth complex surfaces of these degrees have Picard groups of rank 2 and 7 respectively.